# sql query a varchar(max) column to select an element based on the value of one of its children children's

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I am trying to search xml data stored in a varchar(max) column.
Below is an example of one of the xml data strings found in the varchar column
With this example I will have sql variable called @dsName which is to be matched against the node  when its values matches @dsName and it is subordinate to either  or  nodes.  The nodes in between  or  until you get to  can vary.

```
   <business_process>
<ProcessDefinition name="dawns test">
    <StartState name="START" uniqueId="Node3304">
        <Transition name="Node4532" to="Node4532"/>
    </StartState>
    <EndState name="END4694" uniqueId="Node4694"/>
    <User name="Node4532" uniqueId="Node4532">
        <Description>test</Description>
        <Distribution config-type="field" type="CommonQueueDistribution">
            <Priority>0</Priority>
            <AutoCompleteJob>false</AutoCompleteJob>
            <GroupId>Admin</GroupId>
            <UseAttendance>false</UseAttendance>
            <UseShifts>false</UseShifts>
            <NotifyActors>false</NotifyActors>
        </Distribution>
        <DocFinityTask type="DocFinityTask">
            <description>read e-mail and approve or deny</description>
            <help/>
            <required>false</required>
            <redoable>false</redoable>
            <condition/>
            <properties>
                <undoable>true</undoable>
            </properties>
        </DocFinityTask>
        <DocFinityTask type="SimpleFormTask">
            <description>lob lookup</description>
            <help/>
            <required>false</required>
            <redoable>true</redoable>
            <condition/>
            <properties>
                <autoRun>true</autoRun>
                <form>
                    <title>lob</title>
                    <formElement>
                        <type>Combobox</type>
                        <variable>lob</variable>
                        <tooltip>lob lookup</tooltip>
                        <label>lob</label>
                        <required>false</required>
                        <prepopulateValues>
                            <datasourceName>lob lookup</datasourceName>
                        </prepopulateValues>
                        <userEnter>true</userEnter>
                        <dataType>STRING</dataType>
                    </formElement>
                </form>
            </properties>
        </DocFinityTask>
        <Transition name="Node128795" to="Node128795"/>
    </User>
    <Server name="Node128795" uniqueId="Node128795">
        <Description/>
        <Event type="node-enter">
            <Action type="SetProcessInstancePropertyAction" config-type="field">
                <description>Whatever</description>
                <propertyName>source</propertyName>
                <datasourceName>get datasource list</datasourceName>
            </Action>
        </Event>
        <Transition name="Node4694" to="END4694"/>
    </Server>
    <Server name="Node250" uniqueId="Node250">
      <Description />
      <Event type="node-enter">
        <Action type="SetProcessInstancePropertyAction" config-type="field">
          <description>Whatever</description>
          <propertyName>source</propertyName>
          <datasourceName>stump</datasourceName>
        </Action>
      </Event>
      <Transition name="Node4694" to="END4694" />
    </Server>
</ProcessDefinition>
<Layout>
    <annotations/>
    <nodes>
        <node name="START" uniqueId="Node3304" type="startNode" text="START" x="184.5" y="135.5" width="25" height="25"/>
        <node name="END4694" uniqueId="Node4694" type="endNode" text="END4694" x="588.5" y="137.5" width="25" height="25"/>
        <node name="Node4532" uniqueId="Node4532" type="userNode" text="Node4532" info="false" x="296" y="135" width="150" height="50"/>
        <node name="Node128795" uniqueId="Node128795" type="serverNode" text="Node128795" info="false" x="286" y="244" width="150" height="50"/>
    </nodes>
    <edges>
        <edge originNode="Node3304" targetNode="Node4532" text="" sketch="arrow"/>
        <edge originNode="Node4532" targetNode="Node128795" text="" sketch="arrow"/>
        <edge originNode="Node128795" targetNode="Node4694" text="" sketch="arrow"/>
    </edges>
</Layout>
```

Here is an example of the select I used when trying to load into a variable of an XML data type.  The varchar(max) column name is XML

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
            (SELECT [XML] 
             FROM ProcessModels 
             WHERE [XML] LIKE '%<datasourceName>' + @dsName + '%' 
                    and [status] = 'ACTIVE')
```

The SQL select is that same if I load it into a table variable and the @dsName variable is already set with the string to search for.

In this example I want to find name of every Server node and/or User node when it has a  node with the value of 'get datasource list'.  The string 'get datasource list' already exists in the variable @dsName.

The following query gets me half way there.

```
select sn.value('@name', 'varchar(100)') AS ServerNodes
from @xml.nodes('/business_process/ProcessDefinition/Server')  AS ServerNodes(sn)
```

Now I need to figure out how to limit the Server.@name returned to just those where the child node //datasourceName value equals the sql:variable.

This worked:

```
SELECT ServerNode.value('@name','varchar(max)') AS ServerNode
FROM @xml.nodes('/business_process/ProcessDefinition') AS ProcessDefinition(pd)
OUTER APPLY pd.nodes('Server[Event//datasourceName=sql:variable("@searchVariable")]') AS The(ServerNode)
WHERE ServerNode.value('@name','varchar(max)') IS NOT NULL

SELECT UserNode.value('@name','varchar(max)') AS UserNode
FROM @xml.nodes('/business_process/ProcessDefinition') AS ProcessDefinition(pd)
OUTER APPLY pd.nodes('User[DocFinityTask//datasourceName=sql:variable("@searchVariable")]') AS The(UserNode)
WHERE UserNode.value('@name','varchar(max)') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The schema of your sample XML fragment doesn't seem to correspond with the xpath expression in your query (no `/business_process/ProcessDefinition` elements or `datasourceName` attribute). Is this deliberate?

Comment: Correct, I mocked up the example and forgot to change the query to match.  I was just trying to simplify it a bit.

Comment: @Shnugo, I am not sure I get the whole voting thing and this is only the second question I submitted ever.  Mostly I can find what I need by searching existing questions.  What I am trying to do is search for all Server and User nodes in the XML and return the name property for those that have a child node of datasourceName with a value equal to my sql variable then return the name value of the Server or User node.  There can be multiple Server and User nodes in the xml.  I have yet to finding a way to that with xquery so I may have to look at taking a different approach.

Comment: @Fillister, did you check my [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36066771/5089204)? I think this is exactly what you need... Add "voting": There are two things you can do: Each contribution an be good or bad. You should use your right to vote really generously and whereever you walk around on SO. Find a good answer? Great! Vote it! Find something dumb? Vote it! As the question giver you have - additionally - the right to accept the best answer (the check below the vote counter). This marks a question as solved.

Comment: @Shnugo, I did try your second answer but it returns values for User no matter what.  I need the User node to be handled just like the Server node and I could not figure out how to modify it to make that happen.    Thanks for the clarification on voting.  I will work on voting so that I give credit for all of the great information you and others provide.

Comment: @Fillister, just add a `WHERE ServerNode.value('@name','varchar(max)') IS NOT NULL` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my first answer is already very crowded...

With this you'd get the User's and the Server's data out of the XML. If you set the `@searchVariable` to a non existent datasourceName-value, the User data is still there, but the Server data will be NULL. Try it out!

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<business_process>
  <ProcessDefinition name="dawns test">
    <StartState name="START" uniqueId="Node3304">
      <Transition name="Node4532" to="Node4532" />
    </StartState>
    <EndState name="END4694" uniqueId="Node4694" />
    <User name="Node4532" uniqueId="Node4532">
      <Description>test</Description>
      <Distribution config-type="field" type="CommonQueueDistribution">
        <Priority>0</Priority>
        <AutoCompleteJob>false</AutoCompleteJob>
        <GroupId>Admin</GroupId>
        <UseAttendance>false</UseAttendance>
        <UseShifts>false</UseShifts>
        <NotifyActors>false</NotifyActors>
      </Distribution>
      <DocFinityTask type="DocFinityTask">
        <description>read e-mail and approve or deny</description>
        <help />
        <required>false</required>
        <redoable>false</redoable>
        <condition />
        <properties>
          <undoable>true</undoable>
        </properties>
      </DocFinityTask>
      <DocFinityTask type="SimpleFormTask">
        <description>lob lookup</description>
        <help />
        <required>false</required>
        <redoable>true</redoable>
        <condition />
        <properties>
          <autoRun>true</autoRun>
          <form>
            <title>lob</title>
            <formElement>
              <type>Combobox</type>
              <variable>lob</variable>
              <tooltip>lob lookup</tooltip>
              <label>lob</label>
              <required>false</required>
              <prepopulateValues>
                <datasourceName>lob lookup</datasourceName>
              </prepopulateValues>
              <userEnter>true</userEnter>
              <dataType>STRING</dataType>
            </formElement>
          </form>
        </properties>
      </DocFinityTask>
      <Transition name="Node128795" to="Node128795" />
    </User>
    <Server name="Node128795" uniqueId="Node128795">
      <Description />
      <Event type="node-enter">
        <Action type="SetProcessInstancePropertyAction" config-type="field">
          <description>Whatever</description>
          <propertyName>source</propertyName>
          <datasourceName>get datasource list</datasourceName>
        </Action>
      </Event>
      <Transition name="Node4694" to="END4694" />
    </Server>
  </ProcessDefinition>
  <Layout>
    <annotations />
    <nodes>
      <node name="START" uniqueId="Node3304" type="startNode" text="START" x="184.5" y="135.5" width="25" height="25" />
      <node name="END4694" uniqueId="Node4694" type="endNode" text="END4694" x="588.5" y="137.5" width="25" height="25" />
      <node name="Node4532" uniqueId="Node4532" type="userNode" text="Node4532" info="false" x="296" y="135" width="150" height="50" />
      <node name="Node128795" uniqueId="Node128795" type="serverNode" text="Node128795" info="false" x="286" y="244" width="150" height="50" />
    </nodes>
    <edges>
      <edge originNode="Node3304" targetNode="Node4532" text="" sketch="arrow" />
      <edge originNode="Node4532" targetNode="Node128795" text="" sketch="arrow" />
      <edge originNode="Node128795" targetNode="Node4694" text="" sketch="arrow" />
    </edges>
  </Layout>
</business_process>';

DECLARE @searchVariable VARCHAR(100)='get datasource list';

SELECT ServerNode.value('@name','varchar(max)') AS ServerName
      ,ServerNode.value('@uniqueId','varchar(max)') AS ServerId
      ,pd.value('User[1]/@name','varchar(max)') AS UserName
      ,pd.value('User[1]/@uniqueId','varchar(max)') AS UserId
FROM @xml.nodes('/business_process/ProcessDefinition') AS ProcessDefinition(pd)
OUTER APPLY pd.nodes('Server[Event/Action/datasourceName=sql:variable("@searchVariable")]') AS The(ServerNode);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is `sql:variable()`, there is also a `sql:column()` if your search value comes from a table's column.

According to your comment I mock up one table with an XML column of type `varchar`. The `SELECT` will first use `CROSS APPLY` to cast this to "real" XML, then `.exist()` is used to pick up the rows fullfilling your criteria and finally the value of `/User/@name` is returned.

If you change the lookup-variable to "another" you'll find the other XML, other strings will come back empty.

As examples of XPath I give you three queries all returning the same. This depends on your XML...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourXMLAsVarchar VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
('<User name="First Node" uniqueId="1332">
    <Task type="Form">
      <properties>
        <form>
          <formElement>
            <populateValues>
              <source>lookup</source>
            </populateValues>
          </formElement>
        </form>
      </properties>
    </Task>
   </User>')
,('<User name="First Node" uniqueId="1332">
    <Task type="Form">
      <properties>
        <form>
          <formElement>
            <populateValues>
              <source>another</source>
            </populateValues>
          </formElement>
        </form>
      </properties>
    </Task>
   </User>');


--Search for "lookup"
DECLARE @SearchingFor VARCHAR(100)='lookup';

--Search with full path
SELECT x.value('(/User/@name)[1]','varchar(max)')
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(YourXMLAsVarchar AS XML)) AS a(x)
WHERE x.exist('/User/Task/properties/form/formElement/populateValues/source[.=sql:variable("@SearchingFor")]')=1

--shorter, if there is not other "source" element this could be muddled up with...
SELECT x.value('(/User/@name)[1]','varchar(max)')
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(YourXMLAsVarchar AS XML)) AS a(x)
WHERE x.exist('//source[.=sql:variable("@SearchingFor")]')=1

--even shorter, if your lookup string won't be anywhere else an element's value
SELECT x.value('(/User/@name)[1]','varchar(max)')
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(YourXMLAsVarchar AS XML)) AS a(x)
WHERE x.exist('//*[.=sql:variable("@SearchingFor")]')=1
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow you.  I am pulling the xml data from a table column with the data type of varchar(max) and placing it in a variable with the xml data type.  It is SQL Server 2008R2 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hi @Fillister, I don't know what exactly you are doing... In my example I filled a test table with a *varchar* column with two different XMLs. The select will read this column, cast it *on the fly* to XML within the `CROSS APPLY` and then use `.exist()` as filter. You might use `.nodes()` and other XML methods too. So: 1) Is it necessary to use a *declared* XML variable? 2) Are you dealing with just  one XML or do you handle more than one at once? What happens if you just use your own approach, but use `sql:variable()` to get your value into the `XPath`?

Comment: The column is named XML and it is set to varchar(max) data type.  There is only ever on XML in the column.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that I am good with SQL but new to XQuery.  The column is named XML and it is set to varchar(max) data type.  There is only ever on XML in the column.  The goal is to get the xml data from that column and find the name attribute for the User tag when there is a sub-tag named Source with a value that matched my sql variable.  I am afraid that I do not know xquery or xml enough to use the correct terminology.

Comment: @Fillister, my example uses a *declared* table for test case. As you have it, the XML is put as varchar there. Should be quite close to what you have. Please edit your question to add the expected output. Should be easy to get what you want ...

Comment: Shnugo,  Let us say that my sql variable = lookup.  If you use my original xml example, I want to search the xml for when Source = lookup and return the name attribute for User.  I only want the User/name attribute returned when it has a child named Source with a value equal to my variable.

Comment: @Fillister Is there always exactly **one** User per row in your XML column?

Comment: Yes.  There will only ever be one value for User.

Comment: Shnugo, Thank you very much.  This looks like what I need.  Unfortunately I will not be able to test for a while.  I will be out of town for the next 10 days but I will test it as soon as I get back.  Thanks,

Comment: @Fillister I wish you a nice time!

Comment: @Fillister You should consider changing the data type to [`XML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403385.aspx) rather than having it be `VARCHAR(MAX)`

Comment: Changing the data type of the column is out of my control.

Comment: Is there a way I can add another example to this forum?  I only see a way to add comments.  I can provide a live example of the xml data.

Comment: There's an edit option below your query. This allows you to change or enhance the existing question. And please poste a comment with `@Shnugo` below this comment to send me a notification.

Comment: @Shnugo, thanks for the welcome back.  The trip went very well until the last night when guy decided to exit the boat early.  I hope my revised example makes more sense.

Comment: @Fillister, OK, I see the new XML. Do I understand this correctly: You have lots of them in your table in one `VARCHAR` column. Then you want to filter the rows, where the XML has a given value in the `<datasourceName>` element?

Comment: @Shnugo, It is possible that one or more rows would qualify with my select statement and that each xml string returned could have one or more Server and/or User nodes with the dsName value.  My focus has been on trying to parse the data from a single result because I just starting with xml data via SQL Server.  Ultimately I want to be able to loop through n results, checking each for a match.  My thought was to use two separate queries for User and Server nodes so that I could easily distinguish the type of node the result is associated with.

Comment: @Fillister please update your question once more and add the expected output corresponding the given XML. I can show you how to get these data out of it - but at the moment I do not know what you are really trying to achieve...

Comment: @Shnugo, I added a bit to the bottom of my example.  If you can help find the name parameter of the Server node when the datasourceName = the dsName variable = 'get datasource list', I think I can get the rest myself.

Comment: Hi @Fillister, this answer is to crowded already, I added another answer. Hope this will be clear for you...

Answer (score 1):

Yet another alternative. This doesn't use [`XML.exist`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) but looks straight for User elements having a `<source>` element with the lookup variable. Then the path is reversed back to ancestor `User` and the `name` attribute is selected.

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<User name="First Node" uniqueId="1332">
    <Task type="Form">
        <properties>
            <form>
                <formElement>
                    <populateValues>
                        <source>lookup</source>
                    </populateValues>
                </formElement>
            </form>
        </properties>
    </Task>
</User>';

DECLARE @lookup NVARCHAR(128)='lookup';

SELECT
    n.v.value('../../../../../../@name','NVARCHAR(128)') AS name
FROM
    @xml.nodes('//User/Task/properties/form/formElement/populateValues/source[.=sql:variable("@lookup")]') AS n(v);
```

Apparantly XPath axes aren't fully supported (at least not on SQL Server 2012). If it were instead of `../../../../../../@name` you could have written the easier `ancestor::User/@name`.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.  But I get a null value If I use your method or the one offered by Shnugo.

Comment: @Fillister So you copy pasted the excerpt I posted, and you got NULL values? Or you used it with a different XML?

Comment: I modified it to use with the example that I just posted and I misspoke.  It returned nothing at all.  I can post the what I modified it to if you would like?